# Integrating Differential Forms

Tags: calculus, integration, differential

This is part of a homework problem. I want to actually solve it myself, so no solutions, please (although this isn't even the full problem statement). I don't have a very good grasp on differential forms and pullbacks though, so I need to make sure I'm on the right track.

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$, $\alpha : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ be defined by $\alpha(u,v) = (u,v,u^2+v^2+1)$, and $Y = \alpha(A)$. I want to compute $\int_{Y_\alpha}\omega$, where $\omega = x_2dx_2\wedge dx_3$.

Computing $\alpha^* \omega$ gives me $v dv \wedge du$. Then $\int_{Y_\alpha}\omega = \int_A \alpha^* \omega = \int_A v dv\wedge du = \int_A v\ dvdu$ and I just evaluate it as a two-dimensional integral.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, $dx_2 = dv$ and $dx_3 =2udu + 2vdv$, so what is $dx_2 \wedge dx_3$?

Comment: Whoops, I derped and miscopied something.

$\alpha^* (x_2 dx_2 \wedge d_x3) = v(dv)\wedge(2udu+2vdv)$

...Maybe? So I just distribute and carry on from there?

Comment: Yup, and use the fact that wedge product is alternating and the fact that $dv \wedge dv = 0$.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Is it okay if I post in this comment thread if I get stuck?
Also, was the last equality for the integrals correct?

Comment: Won't bother me a bit-- of course if you want to get the attention of other mathematicians online who can help you, then posting a separate question is also an option.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why $dx_2 \wedge dx_3 = dx_2dx_3$ or direct me to some reading?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, remember that the *definition* of the integral of $fdx_1\wedge dx_2$ is $\int fdx_1dx_2$. But I wouldn't directly write that $dx_1\wedge dx_2 = dx_1dx_2$.